# angular material customization guidelines

Tags: javascript, angular, material-ui, angular-material

the material guidelines specify that:

*"For any Angular Material component, you can safely define custom CSS for a component's host element that affect the positioning or layout of that component, such as margin, position, top, left, transform, and z-index. You should apply such styles by defining a custom CSS class and applying that class to the component's host element.
Avoid defining custom styles that would affect the size or internal layout of the component, such as padding, height, width, or overflow. You can specify display: none to hide a component, but avoid specifying any other display value. Overriding these properties can break components in unexpected ways as the internal styles change between releases."*

Does this mean that i really cannot play with, let's say, button width? And make a button have a min-width or maybe have it width 100% ?
That seems so restrictive. Woudld someone be able to clarify these guidelines or know where i could get better clarification?

Answer (score 0):

The section you quote differentiates between "a component's host element" and the component itself. You should treat the component itself as a blackbox, i.e. you should apply layout changes to the host-element, and then let the component figure out how it should deal with it.

On the other hand is the section about general controls, which can be quite complex. For simple controls, you could probably apply your own judgement and changes them as needed.

That being said, Material Design comes with some very strict specification (for example [for buttons](https://m3.material.io/components/buttons/specs)) and it may be be a good idea to follow the "official" design principles and sizes.

Comment: when they say host element, does it mean the button itself, like: <button mat-button class="mybutton">Basic</button>, then i can modify the button? or does it mean <div calss="mybutton"><button mat-button>Basic</button></div> ?

Comment: If the last option, i will never be able to do a 100% width on a button, for instance. Or set min-width

Comment: @solarapricot yes. look at this example here: https://angular.io/guide/directive-composition-api#adding-directives-to-a-component  here they apply a directive  to the "host element" and then specifiy how that change would manifest in the dom.